# Calculations in R with Missing Values

Tags: r, missing-data

In the below test data, v4 is calculated out of v1, v2 and v3 as follows:

```
test$v4 <- (test$v1 + test$v2 + test$v3) / 3
```

As expected, any row with a missing value returns an NA result for v4:

```
  v1 v2 v3       v4
1  1  1  2 1.333333
2  1  1  2 1.333333
3  1  2 NA       NA
4  0  1 NA       NA
5 NA NA  0       NA
6 NA  1  0       NA
7  1  2 NA       NA
```

However, I want R to return an NA only when there are two or three NA values. If there is only one NA, I want R to calculate the mean of the two available values.

Can you please advise as to how I can do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` and `rowSums(is.na())` to have differing formula on different rows:

```
dat <- read.table(text=  "v1 v2 v3       v4
1  1  1  2 1.333333
           2  1  1  2 1.333333
           3  1  2 NA       NA
           4  0  1 NA       NA
           5 NA NA  0       NA
           6 NA  1  0       NA
           7  1  2 NA       NA")
# if more than 2 NAs in each row, NA, otherwise the mean ignoring NAs
dat$v4 <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(dat)) >= 2, NA, rowMeans(dat, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I specify which variables to average out when I work with a large data set?

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.